# Creating a TFS project from a silverlight application

Tags: silverlight

I am developing a Silverlight application that displays a dashboard of builds from TFS and I just found out that I cant reference TFS libraries from Silverlight as they are built with different runtime. Whats the workaround? Is their a Silverlight clr version of TFS libraries I can reference?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to accomplish this by using the TFS OData API available here: https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/